# Best practices for parameterizing load of multiple CSV files in Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am experimenting with Azure Data Factory to replace some other data-load solutions we currently have, and I'm struggling with finding the best way to organize and parameterize the pipelines to provide the scalability we need.

Our typical pattern is that we build an integration for a particular Platform. This "integration" is essentially the mapping and transform of fields from their data files (CSVs) into our Stage1 SQL database, and by the time the data lands in there, the data types should be set properly and the indexes set.

Within each Platform, we have Customers. Each Customer has their own set of data files that get processed in that Customer context -- within the scope of a Platform, all Customer files follow the same schema (or close to it), but they all get sent to us separately. If you looked at our incoming file store, it might look like (simplified, there are 20-30 source datasets per customer depending on platform):

1. Platform

   1. Customer A

      1. Employees.csv
      2. PayPeriods.csv
      3. etc
   2. Customer B

      1. Employees.csv
      2. PayPeriods.csv
      3. etc

Each customer lands in their own SQL schema. So after processing the above, I should have CustomerA.Employees and CustomerB.Employees tables. (This allows a little bit of schema drift between customers, which does happen on some platforms. We handle it later in our stage 2 ETL process.)

What I'm trying to figure out is:

What is the best way to setup ADF so I can effectively manage one set of mappings per platform, and automatically accommodate any new customers we add to that platform without having to change the pipeline/flow?

My current thinking is to have one pipeline per platform, and one dataflow per file per platform. The pipeline has a variable, "schemaname", which is set using the path of the file that triggered it (e.g. "CustomerA"). Then, depending on file name, there is a branching conditional that will fire the right dataflow. E.g. if it's "employees.csv" it runs one dataflow, if it's "payperiods.csv" it loads a different dataflow. Also, they'd all be using the same generic target sink datasource, the table name being parameterized and those parameters being set in the pipeline using the schema variable and the filename from the conditional branch.

Are there any pitfalls to setting it up this way? Am I thinking about this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds solid. Just be aware that you if you define column-specific mappings with expressions that expect those columns to be present, you may have data flow execution failures if those columns are not present in your customer source files.

The ways to protect against that in ADF Data Flow is to use column patterns. This will allow you to define mappings that are generic and more flexible.